# Map display with release key in android

Tags: android, android-maps

I've created Release key for my application.But It doesnt show map.What did i wrong on that?i've created release key by Right click of project->Export->Giving alias_name->...like that.Then by the use of Keytool.,i got that release key.i used it on my xml.

My code:

```
public class SampleMapActivity extends MapActivity {

    MapView         myMapView       = null;

    MapController   myMC            = null;

    GeoPoint        geoPoint        = null;

    double          latitude        = 12.937875, longitude = 77.622313;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myGMap);
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1000020), (int) (longitude * 1000020));
        myMapView.setStreetView(true);

        myMC = myMapView.getController();
        myMC.setCenter(geoPoint);
        myMC.setZoom(15);

        myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myMapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I) {
            myMapView.getController().setZoom(myMapView.getZoomLevel() + 1);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O) {
            myMapView.getController().setZoom(myMapView.getZoomLevel() - 1);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
            myMapView.setSatellite(true);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_M) {
            myMapView.setSatellite(false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/myGMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0GNnbje3crS0ZuqJfAFnJjO8zNPYy9OqNzHS2Aw"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

lets go for get MapAPIKey.

**1)How to create KeyStore**

```
Project >> Export >> ExportAndroidApplication >> Next >> Create New Keystore (Remember Keystore Path) >> Fill All Detail >> ...etc
```

Now your keystore and Apk is created.

**2)How to get Certificate fingerprint (MD5)**

```
$ keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

for more detail [go here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

Now you got fingerprint like as

`Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 94:1E:43:49:87:73:BB:E6:A6:88:D7:20:F1:8E:B5:98`

**3)How to get MapApiKey**
[click here](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html) and paste your MD5 then u will get MapAPIKey.
Use this key in your application.

**4)Test**

create new apk using this keystore and check..