# Generating google map API for android is not displaying map

Tags: android, android-maps, ubuntu-11.04

Some one please help me out of this ::(

I am using `ubuntu 11.04 OS, Eclipse and Google+Android 2.2`

My android application includes google map and so I signed and generated my google API key
but when running my application my map is not displayed but only the grid view.

I used cmd to sign the API key and to generate MD5 finger print. My steps are as follows:

- I directed to the keystore directory through this command --> `~/.android/`
- Then I signed using this command-->

> ```
> keytool -genkey -v -keystore
>    my-release-key.keystore -alias release_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize
>    2048 -validity 10000
> ```

- An output came like this

> [Storing my-release-key.keystore].

- Then I changed the directory to this path-->`/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/`
- and executed this command `"sudo su"`.

Now I gave the path to the keystore I generated (`my-release-key.keystore`).

Finally I generated my MD5 fingerprint

> FE:30:45:17:46:1F:18:0E:8D:0B:36:F5:8F:04:81:D8

I copied the same into the sign up.

**But now am getting only the grid view but not the map :( :( :(**

Someone please help me out of this.. I had been trying for this for an week :( :(

Hi to everybody who answered me.. Now I got the map in my emulator. The following command worked for me :) And thanks to all:)

> og-admin@Android2:~$ cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/
>   og-admin@Android2:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin$  keytool -list
>   -keystore /home/og-admin/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
>
> Keystore type: JKS Keystore provider: SUN
>
> Your keystore contains 1 entry
>
> androiddebugkey, Jul 21, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry,  Certificate
>   fingerprint (MD5): B4:6C:93:21:C6:6D:50:0B:1B:64:15:5D:FA:1F:2D:B1
>   og-admin@Android2:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin$

Comment: The key that you signed your application must be the same by which you had generated your MD5 fingerprint.

Comment: I too had the same problem. i create the api key once again and replace the new api problem was solved..so may be you too have  problem in api key. Whether its running successful in emulator with debug key?

Comment: Sorry Umesh, I can't get you correctly.....

Comment: @deepa application is running successfully but am not getting the map. Do you mean that create new and delete the old api key i generated?

Comment: sorry, i ask whether its displaying map in emulator with debug key or not?

Comment: Then generate api key correctly as per in this link http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html  and for getting release key just follow steps as per in following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267238/map-display-with-release-key-in-android/6277792#6277792

Comment: Hi i got the map through this command :) Thanks for your reply :) og-admin@Android2:~$ cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/
og-admin@Android2:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin$  keytool -list -keystore /home/og-admin/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

androiddebugkey, Jul 21, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): B4:6C:93:21:C6:6D:50:0B:1B:64:15:5D:FA:1F:2D:B1
og-admin@Android2:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your reply:) I got the map through this command..

og-admin@Android2:~$ cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/ og-admin@Android2:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin$ keytool -list -keystore /home/og-admin/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

Keystore type: JKS Keystore provider: SUN Your keystore contains 1 entry androiddebugkey, Jul 21, 2011,

PrivateKeyEntry, Certificate fingerprint (MD5): B4:6C:93:21:C6:6D:50:0B:1B:64:15:5D:FA:1F:2D:B1 og-admin@Android2:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin$

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once before. I had forgotten to put 
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
in the manifest. Which gave the app permission to download the tiles.

Comment: this is my manifest file                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
          
        <activity android:name="Map"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

Comment: If you are testing the app through the emulator or installing over adb your maps will be signed using the debug keystore. In the below link follow the instructions under Getting the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint

Comment: Can you explain me the steps what i want to do to generate the api key ?

Comment: Here is a video I put together as a walk through You are most likely signing your app with the debug keystore and you are using a release key to generate your API key. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gc5-kpppVdg

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply:) I got the map through this command..                                        og-admin@Android2:~$ cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/
og-admin@Android2:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin$  keytool -list -keystore /home/og-admin/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

androiddebugkey, Jul 21, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): B4:6C:93:21:C6:6D:50:0B:1B:64:15:5D:FA:1F:2D:B1
og-admin@Android2:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin$