# My android application won't run on 2 devices but works on emulator

Tags: android, maps, android-virtual-device

I'm writing an application that displays Google Map right after the login screen.
The Build Target is set to 2.3 and my devices run:

1) Samsung Galaxy Ace (2.3.4)
2) Motorolla Xoom (3.1)

I try my app on the Android emulator and it runs fine. Login and map display.

When I connected both devices via USB on my computer and selected them to run the application (note: there was an orange warning sign next to the build target when selecting), the login screen appears just fine and when I click "Sign In" the application crashes on Motorolla and freezes and for a while and then does nothing on my Galaxy Ace.

Note that they can both connect to the internet.

Logcat for the devices while running the app through USB connection:

1) Samsung Galaxy Ace

```
04-06 00:24:21.599: I/InputReader(162): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
04-06 00:24:21.599: I/InputDispatcher(162): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '40796920 com.cylbs.android/com.cylbs.android.MainActivity (server)'
04-06 00:24:21.699: I/InputReader(162): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
04-06 00:24:21.699: I/InputDispatcher(162): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '40796920 com.cylbs.android/com.cylbs.android.MainActivity (server)'
04-06 00:24:27.709: W/PowerManagerService(162): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x1
04-06 00:24:28.559: D/BatteryService(162): update start
04-06 00:24:28.569: D/BatteryService(162): update start
04-06 00:24:28.579: D/BatteryService(162): update start
```

2) Motorolla Xoom

```
04-06 00:27:13.490: D/AndroidRuntime(3163): Shutting down VM
04-06 00:27:13.490: W/dalvikvm(3163): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40154760)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:368)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:208)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:431)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:901)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:624)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at com.cylbs.android.MainActivity.tryLogin(MainActivity.java:65)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at com.cylbs.android.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my code for the MainActivity which is only Login and the Home activity which is where the map appears:

MainActivity:

```
package com.cylbs.android;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button login;
    private EditText username, password;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logIn);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String   mUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String  mPassword = password.getText().toString();

                tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword);

            }
        });
    }

    public boolean tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword)
    {           
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        OutputStreamWriter request = null;

            URL url = null;   
            String response = null;         
            String parameters = "username="+mUsername+"&password="+mPassword;   
            final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

            try
            {
                url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/database_test/index.php");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                request.write(parameters);
                request.flush();
                request.close();            
                String line = "";               
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                
                response = sb.toString();
                // You can perform UI operations here
                Toast.makeText(this,"."+ response +".", 0).show();          


                if (response.equals("Success"))
                {
                    Session obj = new Session();
                    obj.setUsername(mUsername);

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    result.setText("Login successful");
                }   
                else
                {
                    result.setText("Login fail. Please try again");
                }
                isr.close();
                reader.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                // Error
            }
            return true;
    }

}
```

And the Home activity (extends MapActivity)

```
package com.cylbs.android;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Home extends MapActivity {

    MapController mControl;
    GeoPoint geoP;
    MapView mapV;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        mapV = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapV.displayZoomControls(true);
        mapV.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        double lat = 40.8;
        double longi = -96.666;

        geoP = new GeoPoint((int) (lat *1E6), (int) (longi *1E6));

        mControl = mapV.getController();
        mControl.animateTo(geoP);
        mControl.setZoom(13);


        Button emergencies = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emergencyButton);
        emergencies.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Home.this, EmergencyList.class);
                Home.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        Button disruptions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disruptionButton);
        disruptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(Home.this, DisruptionList.class);
                startActivity(myIntent2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thoughts?
It's all for now.
Thank you so much.

P.S.
I'm a new android developer.

Comment: What did the orange warning sign mean? What was the error in Logcat when it crashed? What do you mean it "does nothing" on the Ace? Not sure what you mean exactly. Does it work on any other actual devices?

Comment: There is a yellow warning icon next to several phones that work fine with all of my apps, so I would guess that  is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same issue I think I have found a solution.

I looked up the error in LogCat:

```
04-06 00:27:13.510: E/AndroidRuntime(3163): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

And according to this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

it seems that some (newer) android versions don't allow internet connection requests in the MainActivity or something like that.

Even though I was targetting android version 10 (2.3) I still had the error so I changed my project target to version 8 and it seems to work okay now.

Answer (score 1):

I presuppose you are using a diferente Maps API KEY for emulating the app, and another different signed with your MD5 signature to run the app on devices. Check it out [here](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html).

Comment: +1 for this, usually the map activity will just look like a blank grid, but this is a good place to start

Comment: @Pelanes

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Since it's the same application with the same code running on the emulator and the same exactly running on both my devices...

Also please note that when I first generated the Maps API KEY all I got was grey grids (on my emulator. still doesn't run on devices).

Then, I saw a CornBoyzAndroid tutorial on YouTube and I created a Maps API Key for debugging which allowed my map to load perfectly on the emulator, but still doesn't work on my devices.

Comment: @RobLourens

Orange sign is this:
http://i44.tinypic.com/e9hk07.png

On the Ace when I click Sign In (the step before the map) it just doesn't respond, and then it responds but it is as if I haven't pressed anything. If I press it again it happens again. It does not pop up the "Force Close" message. The Motorolla does though...

The Ace gives up no errors on the LogCat... The Motorolla gives some but I don't really understand them. I saved them in 2 different .txt files. Download them below.

http://www.mediafire.com/?plmhhk9f3p4vflk

Comment: You need a diferent Maps API Key to view maps in real phones, a diferent one from Key for debbuging. Read the link I posted before, you need to know you PC MD5 signature, what keystore you will use to sing apk, and then run a msdos program to obtain this Maps Key.

Comment: Please post the contents of the RAR you linked to above in your question! :)

Comment: @Pelanes

I think you didn't understand that I already did that. I tried with a key for debugging but also tried with a normal one if I can call it that.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6278059/1306468 followed these instructions if it helps you understand what I did.

Comment: yes, if you did that you should have the correct api key. Can you post your activity and activity that extends mapactivity?

Comment: I have checked your MapActivity code with one mine that works fine, and I can't see any difference or mistake :( If the values of lat & lon are real, you must see that place. I think the problem has to be in other place. Try to start in your device only this activity, without logins or anything else, to check it works. Sorry man, good luck.